# Cheap/DIY approach to compressed powder candy

Tags: candy

I'm interested in making tablet-style compressed candies (like sweet tarts or specifically the sticks from lik-m-aid), and while I can find ingredients on store packaging and figure out from there, I don't know how to compress the candies at home. I'd appreciate any advice anyone has on how to do this. So far the only even related recipes I've found have been for making molded candies out of granulated sugar, but I think I need a more technical/high-pressure approach for powdered ingredients to hold together and be hard enough (I am aiming for the hardness of a mint lifesaver basically). Does anyone have any experience or resources?

Comment: This is a cool question. I imagine a cheap press would provide enough pressure but what can you use for the dies/molds.

Comment: Speed is a factor as well, if you have to press each individual candy and then package it you'll be there forever!

Comment: @GdD- I expect the mold would have to be metal and two parts so you could press the parts together and make a large batch at the same time. Doing a quick search I can't find anything like that. A search for "Metal candy press die" only gives me results about the death of John Candy. :/

Answer (score 2):

As a resource, take a look at [[VIDEO]Easter Gift: How to Make Shaped Confections with Candy Tablet Press TDP-0](http://www.kosindustry.com/videoeaster-gift-how-to-make-shaped-confections-with-candy-tablet-press-tdp-0.html)

You will need to provide the die or punch, but the result corresponds to what you're looking for.  Not sure of the price though.

Comment: $800 for the press. With the search term "pill die press" I actually found dies for sale for that machine: $110. https://www.aliexpress.com/item/custom-round-tablet-press-punch-die-pill-press-die-die-press-for-tablet-pill-press-machine/32363523790.html